# Azure DevOps - Batching using pipeline trigger

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to trigger my release pipeline, when the build pipeline "functionAppBuildPipeline" completes. Based on the below code it is working fine. But I would like queue up the release if there is an active one.

I tried with `batch: true` but that is not supported with pipeline trigger and only supported with CI trigger.

Is there any way to limit the release pipeline run concurrency to 1?

Note:

- I have the same pipeline running in DEV,TEST,SIT and PROD (based on environment). The concurrency would like to set it up based on environment level.
- There are multiple release pipeline in each environment to release different azure service, so limiting the concurrency in agent level would affect other release. Would like to have solution in pipeline and environment level.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: functionAppBuildPipeline
    source: function-apps-build-Repo
    trigger:      
      branches:
        include:
        - master 
        - feature/integration

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
```

I have tried with the following code and does not worked

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: functionAppBuild
    source: 06-dh-function-apps-build
    trigger:
      batch: true
      branches:
        include:
        - master
        - feature/integration

trigger:
- none
```

Answer (score 0):

You have [exclusive lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true&tabs=check-pass#exclusive-lock) which first you need to enable for environment:

[image]

And then you can set for sequential runs or latest:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  lockBehavior: sequential
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!
```

> The exclusive lock check allows only a single run from the pipeline to proceed

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Madej for the response!

Comment: The Lock is applicable to the environment and the other release pipelines that using ENV get queued, Is there a way to limit it based on pipeline level rather than the whole ENV.